# Invisible percent sign in UILabel - possible bug

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` containing a single percent sign -> `@"%"`.

When the font size is 24, it is visible. When the font size is 38, it is not visible.

The size of the `UILabel` is calculated to fit around the text content, and it correct (at least it looks OK when I show the background).

Changing text color does not affect the problem.

The text is visible if I change the text content to almost anything else. For example, if there is whitespace on both sides -> `@" % "`, or if there are two percent signs -> `@"%%"`. (In these cases, the size is larger. In the later case, two percent signs are visible.)

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Here is the frame calculation:

```
CGFloat width = [value.text sizeWithFont:value.font].width;
CGFloat height = [@"A" sizeWithFont:value.font].height;
CGRect frame = value.frame;

frame.size.width = ceilf(width);
frame.size.height = height;
value.frame = frame;
```

Comment: show how you calculate size of label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround that I used was

```
// Workaround for bug where percent symbol is not displayed!
value.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
```